How to delete a file with fully qualified file name having more than 259 characters from the command line?
I try to delete or rename a file from the command line on Windows 11 Professional. I can delete it with Windows File Explorer, but I need to do it also from the command line:
D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final

A dir of the directory displays:
dir "D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114"
Volume in drive D is BACKUP  Volume Serial Number is 8E6F-6103

Directory of D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114
 
08/10/2023  03:10 PM    <DIR>
08/10/2023  03:10 PM    <DIR>
08/10/2023  03:10 PM    1,218 {7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final

But I cannot dir (or del or rename) the file itself:
dir "D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final"
Volume in drive D is BACKUP  Volume Serial Number is 8E6F-6103

 Directory of D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114

File Not Found

If I remove {} from the file name, I can delete it. Furthermore, if I copy the file to a directory with a simpler and shorter path, I can delete it without trouble independent on {} or no {} in file name.
What am I doing wrong?
Added notes:

I do have quotes around the file name.

I am able to delete, dir, rename, just not in this directory.

This is PowerShell from the offending directory (note the long prompt).
Note that PowerShell does pick up the name of the file, but then tell you it does not exist.
D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-04-15 21;14;31 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114>powershell.exe Remove-Item *.*

Remove-Item : An object at the specified path D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-04-15 21;14;31 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++50
5991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final does not exist.   
At line:1 char:1   
+ Remove-Item *.*   
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], PSArgumentException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand


I am able to delete with Windows File Explorer.



The fully qualified file name exceeds indeed the MAX_PATH limitation of 259 characters (plus terminating null byte = 260 single byte per character encoded characters). The solution in a batch file is: for %%I in ("D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-03-26 16;10;20 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%%28https%%2Cbid13.com%%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final") do del /A /F %%~sI That uses the short 8.3 file name of the file.

That works only if the generation of short 8.3 file names is enabled in file system. See also the Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.

Figured it out.
This is the bad call:
C:\NtUtil>del "D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-04-15 21;14;31 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final"
The system cannot find the path specified.

This is the good call:
C:\NtUtil>del "\\?\D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-04-15 21;14;31 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final"
Could Not Find \\?\D:\MyDocsBackup\backup2\Mozilla 2024-04-15 21;14;31 (Full)\Firefox\Profiles\pj0elosu.default-release\storage\default\https+++505991220932649.webpush.freshchat.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cbid13.com%29\cache\morgue\114\{7cccd5e9-a7aa-4349-a2e9-569baf007272}.final

The difference is the \\?\ at the beginning of the filename.  MAX_PATH = 260. The long path in question was 265.  It had nothing to do with the weird characters in the file and path.
Thank you all for the help and tips.

The long fully qualified file name has 261 and not 265 characters not counting the terminating null byte of single byte per character encoded file name.
